# Compiler complains "actual and formal argument lists differ in length", but they do not

Tags: java, generics

When I compile the following code:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collector;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Testcase
{
    public static <T, K, V> Collector<T, ?, ImmutableMap<K, V>> toImmutableMap1(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static <T, K, V> MapCollectorBuilder<T, K, V, ? extends Map<K, V>, ImmutableMap<K, V>>
        toImmutableMap2(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
            Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public final class MapCollectorBuilder<T, K, V, A extends Map<K, V>, R extends Map<K, V>>
    {
        /**
         * @return a new collector
         */
        public Collector<T, A, R> build()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void main(String[] args)
    {
        Function<String, String> keyMapper = i -> i;
        Function<String, Integer> valueMapper = Integer::valueOf;

        ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map1 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3")
            .collect(Testcase.toImmutableMap1(keyMapper, valueMapper));

        MapCollectorBuilder<String, String, Integer, Map<String, Integer>, ImmutableMap<String, Integer>> builder
            = Testcase.
            <String, String, Integer, Map<String, Integer>, ImmutableMap<String, Integer>>toImmutableMap2(
                keyMapper, valueMapper);

        ImmutableMap<String, Integer> map2 = Stream.of("1", "2", "3").collect(builder.build());
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Testcase.java:[45,35] method toImmutableMap2 in class Testcase cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>,java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends V>
  found: java.util.function.Function<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>,java.util.function.Function<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

but as far as I can tell, the argument list is correct.

1. Why does `toImmutableMap1()` compile while `toImmutableMap2()` does not?
2. How can I make `toImmutableMap2()` compile properly?

**UPDATE**: If I replace the 5 type parameters with `<String, String, Integer>` I get this new compiler error:

```
incompatible types: Testcase.MapCollectorBuilder<String,String,Integer,CAP#1,ImmutableMap<String,Integer>> cannot be converted to Testcase.MapCollectorBuilder<String,String,Integer,Map<String,Integer>,ImmutableMap<String,Integer>>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Map<String,Integer> from capture of ? extends Map<String,Integer>
```

Comment: `<String, String, Integer, Map<String, Integer>, ImmutableMap<String, Integer>>` versus `<T, K, V>` ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis This results in a different compiler error. Please post this as an answer so I can respond in more detail without cluttering comments on the question.

Comment: @Gili: Yup, see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're trying to specify 5 type arguments here:

```
Testcase.
    <String, String, Integer, Map<String, Integer>, ImmutableMap<String, Integer>>toImmutableMap2(
```

... but the method only has 3 type parameters:

```
public static <T, K, V> ComplexReturnTypeHere<...> toImmutableMap2
```

You can fix that by changing the call to:

```
Testcase.<String, String, Integer>toImmutableMap2(...)
```

But that changes the error message to:

```
Testcase.java:44: error: incompatible types: 
Testcase.MapCollectorBuilder<String,String,Integer,CAP#1,ImmutableMap<String,Integer>>
cannot be converted to 
Testcase.MapCollectorBuilder<String,String,Integer,Map<String,Integer>,
    ImmutableMap<String,Integer>>
```

That can in turn be fixed by changing the return type of the method declaration:

```
public static <T, K, V>
    MapCollectorBuilder<T, K, V, Map<K, V>, ImmutableMap<K, V>>
    toImmutableMap2(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends V> valueMapper)
```

The difference here is the second type argument in `MapCollectorBuilder` - `Map<K, V>` instead of `? extends Map<K, V>`.

Alternatively, you could change the declaration of `builder` to:

```
MapCollectorBuilder<String, String, Integer, ? extends Map<String, Integer>, ImmutableMap<String, Integer>> builder
```

(Mind you, personally at this point it feels like it's falling into the realm of "incredibly hard to read and understand" code...)

Comment: Thank you, that works. Problem is, this type parameter corresponds to `<A>` in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html. Meaning, I really want users to be able to specify any subclass of `Map`. If I change the type parameter from `? extends Map<K, V>` to `Map<K, V>` as you suggest, won't they lose this ability?

Comment: @Gili: I'm afraid I don't really follow what you're trying to do, but I've given an alternative at the bottom of my answer, changing the type of `builder` instead.

Comment: Thanks Jon. You've helped me realize that my code didn't really need to use wildcards to begin with.